# Does IOS contain some class that can draw line (route) on map

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, core-location, mkpolyline

I have a `MKMapView` and a list of coordinates (*about 50.000 points*).
And for now I am using `MKPolyLine` that draw route on the map.
Basically I loop through all coordinates and draw line between **last** and **next** point.
But I am wondering is there some class in IOS that I can use like pass array of coordinates and load route on map automatically?

Comment: check this link http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136

Comment: I am using the same way to create route now. But my question is: Is there some IOS class that can receive array of coordinates and draw path for me.

Comment: in my answer have demo code of class please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this demo link  . In this demo you will get `CSRouteView` Class .This class for DrawRoute on `MKMapView` directly and only need to pass `coordinates` .

https://github.com/PeyloW/Res-i-Skane

Hope this useful for you.

Comment: @1110 if you safisfied my answer so please support me and upvote please . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `MKPolylineView` and create it with your `MKPolyLine`.

> The MKPolylineView class provides the visual representation for an MKPolyline annotation object. This view strokes the path represented by the annotation.